# In React, how do I make the tbody of an html table scrollable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

for context I'm using React, Node, Express, Postgres to pull data from a db.

I have an html table in a div that spans across the entire screen. The only way I could succeed in making just the table scrollable I had to add `display: block` to the header and body sections. The problem was this floated my table to the left so the header and body sections weren't aligned.

Table in question:

```
<h1>Inventory</h1>
        <div id="Inventory">
            <table className="table" id="InventoryTable">
                <thead id="InventoryHead">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Material</th>
                        <th>Thickness</th>
                        <th>Width</th>
                        <th>Length</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th>Supplier ID</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="InventoryBody">
                    {inventory.map(inventory => (
                            <tr key={inventory.inventory_id}>
                                <td>{inventory.inventory_material}</td>
                                <td>{inventory.inventory_thickness}</td>
                                <td>{inventory.inventory_width}</td>
                                <td>{inventory.inventory_length}</td>
                                <td>{inventory.inventory_quantity}</td>
                                <td>{inventory.supplier_id}</td>
                            </tr>
                        ))}   
                </tbody>
            </table>
            
        </div>
```

CSS used:

```
#Inventory {
  overflow: scroll;
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

Please let me know if there's more info I can provide, thanks!

So far I have tried to use `display: block` to be able to scroll just the tbody. This worked, but it also broke the table structure. As a workaround I applied `overflow: scroll` to the div instead, but this isn't ideal because the table header gets scrolled as well.

Answer (score 0):

just give the table width `#InventoryTable { width: 100% }`.

Answer (score 0):

You can give width of 100% and specify the scroll if you want scroll in horizontal position then overflow-x:scroll. If you want scroll vertically then overflow-y:scroll.

```
#InventoryBody {
Width: 100%;
Overflow-x: scroll;
}
```